# I can't properly change the boolean of an array with prevState

Tags: reactjs, object, setstate

**Thanks everybody trying to answer my previous question. I've just learned how to mutate boolean in my array objects.**

**Now I need to trigger re-render since my object changed but don't know much about life cycles. I'm newbie in react so a bit of hand would be perfect. Thanks folks.**

```
  export default function App() {
      const [obj, setObj] = useState([
        { name: "chicken", comments: "nice", photo: img, boolean: false },
        { name: "beef", comments: "ehh", photo: img, boolean: false },
        { name: "turkey", comments: "not bad", photo: img,  boolean: false },
        { name: "broccoli", comments: "cool", photo: img,  boolean: false },
        { name: "carrot", comments: "disgusting",photo: img, boolean: false }
      ]);
    
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      const idx = e.target.value;
      setObj(prev => {
    prev[idx].boolean = !prev[idx].boolean
    return prev
      });
      window.alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
    
      }
              return (
              <div>
              {obj.map((map, key) => (
                <div>
                  <img src={map.photo} alt={map.key} />
                  <h1>{map.name}</h1>
                  <p>{`${map.boolean}`}</p>
                  <p>{key}</p>
                  <button value={key} onClick={handleClick}>
                    show comments
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is actually what you are doing there, you are spreading an array and adding an item after that! what you could do:

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
    const idx = e.target.value;
    setObj(prev => {
       prev[idx].boolean = true;
       return prev;
      } 
    )
    console.log(obj);
  };
```

this would work most likely.

also for this kind of huge states, I suggest you consider `useReducer` from react.

If I want to complete above:

```
export default function App() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState([...]);
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const idx = e.target.value;
    setObj(prev => {
       prev[idx].boolean = true;
       return prev;
      } 
    )
    setUpdate(prev => !prev);
  };
  return (
    <div className="main-div">
      {obj.map((map, key) => (
        <div className="child-div">
          <img src={map.photo} alt={map.key} />
          <h1>{map.name}</h1>
          <p>{map.boolean ? map.comments : null}</p>
          <button value={key} onClick={handleClick}>
          {map.boolean ? "hide comments" : "show comments"}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will make it work.

Comment: Great. This is what I'm looking for. I can mutate the boolean inside.However, my component doesn't re-renders now. So I can't display the changes in my rendered items. Any suggestions? Thanks a million !

Comment: Sure, using reacts ’useReducer’ will do the trick, have you worked with that? You can do some stuff like forcing an update by changing a state of a boolean with another ’useState’. Something like: [update, setUpdate] = useState(false) and toggling it after setObj

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here

```
setObj(prev => 
      [...prev, prev[idx].boolean = true]
)
```

You're actually pushing another boolean value
modify handleClick function as such

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    const idx = e.target.value;// getting the required idx
    const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); // creating a new obj 
    obj[idx].boolean = true; // setting the newobj boolean value
    setObj(newObj); // useState function to set new state.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what's called a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
[...prev, prev[idx].boolean = true]
```

You basically say.. *Hey, take this object, spread it's values, then assign this new value and append it*. The problem with this is that you're **creating** a new variable `prev[idx].boolean` **NOT assigning** a new value. That's the root of the problem.

Now, what you should do is create this variable outside

```
const value = { ...prev[idx] }
value.boolean = true
```

You should create a new object otherwise it's **passed by reference**.

> In Pass by Reference, a function is called by directly passing the reference/address of the variable as the argument. Changing the argument inside the function affects the variable passed from outside the function. In Javascript objects and arrays are passed by reference.

Then assign it

```
setObj(prev => 
  [...prev, value]
)
```

This means you will override any destructured element with the same value or if it doesn't have any, just assign the new value.

---

## Edit

The problem is that you're mutating the state variable

```
setObj(prev => {
  prev[idx].boolean = !prev[idx].boolean
  return prev
});
```

Do this instead

```
setObj(prev => {
  const value = { ...prev[idx] };
  value.boolean = !value.boolean;
  
  return [...prev, value];
});
```

Or this

```
const value = { ...prev[idx] };
value.boolean = !value.boolean;

setObj([...obj, value]);
```

In my previous response I've quoted **pass by reference**.. you should read it carefully, because you're trying to create a shallow copy of an object which wouldn't be a problem if you didn't care about changing the original object as well.

Since you're trying to change the state, you **CANNOT** change the state variable itself. This is what's happening here

```
prev[idx].boolean = !prev[idx].boolean
return prev
```

You have to create a new object to trigger the re-render lifecycle.

Comment: This actually worked for me. I can mutate the boolean inside.However, my component doesn't re-renders now. So I can't display the changes in my rendered items. Any suggestions? Thanks a million.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code?

Answer (score 0):

**I have finally solved the problem thanks to the contributions of the commenters.**

Here is the problem. I tried to change the state, which is an array of objects. I did it because `prevstate` works on strings and integer types of states (Increment the number button for instance.) However, things get different when mutating objects and arrays.

If you mutate an object, react wont re-render because spreading array method creates a shallow copy. Thanks to [@kmp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13747848/kmp) and others for helping me figure that out.

I had to create a copy of the array to mutate and let react know that state is mutated. The mistaken `setStat` code which works to change boolean but doesn't work to re-render is at the bottom of the code commented out.

I learned a lot from this mistake and I really appreciate the guys who contributed. Cheers.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState([
    { name: "chicken", comments: "nice", photo: img, boolean: false },
    { name: "beef", comments: "ehh", photo: img, boolean: false },
    { name: "turkey", comments: "not bad", photo: img,  boolean: false },
    { name: "broccoli", comments: "cool", photo: img,  boolean: false },
    {
      name: "carrot",
      comments: "disgusting",
      photo: img,
      key: 4,
      boolean: false
    }
  ]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
      const idx = e.target.value;
      const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
      newObj[idx].boolean = !newObj[idx].boolean; 
      setObj(newObj);
  }
  return (
    <div className="main-div">
      {obj.map((map, key) => (
        <div className="child-div">
          <img src={map.photo} alt={map.key} />
          <h1>{map.name}</h1>
          <p>{map.boolean ? map.comments : null}</p>
          <button value={key} onClick={handleClick}>
          {map.boolean ? "hide comments" : "show comments"}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

/*
const idx = e.target.value;
setObj(prev => {
  prev[idx].boolean = !prev[idx].boolean;
  return prev;
})

window.alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
*/
```